# Regular expression to find images that are not smilies in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I search for images in a forum post with this PHP code:

```
if(preg_match("~<img.*src=\"(.*)\".*/>~isU", $htmltext, $imatch))
{
    $imageurl = $imatch[1];
}
```

This will find the first image in the htmltext.
However, I want to skip any images that are smilie icons. All the smilie icons rest in the folder /forum/smilies/.
How can I exclude this folder from the regular expression?

Comment: use preg_match_all instead preg_match to find all images.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to use regex when you try to parse HTML. You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on this same problem.

This will do the trick:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmltext);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$valid  = array();
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
    if ($src !== '' && strpos($src, '/forum/smilies/') !== 0) {
        $valid[] = $src;
    }
}
print_r($valid);
```

`$valid` is an array containing all non-similey `img`'s `src` within the given `$htmltext`.

Comment: yes, use DOM parsing, but in your code it would probably be better to use `stripos`.  Even the [php manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) says: *"Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster."*